# Jquery can't process return value is php code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i'm trying to use simple code to take city name with jquery 
but as result i always got full php code that i command to process, 
although these code i take have o different from the source from internet

here is the code,

#### jquery

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
    var name = $('input#name').val();
    var namempty = '';
    if ($.trim(name) != '') {
        $.post('ajax/name.php', {
            nameSend: name
        }, function(data) {
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
        });
    } else {
        $('div#name-data').text(namempty);
    }
});​
```

#### the php "name.php"

```
if (isset($_POST['nameSend'])=== true && empty($_POST['nameSend']) === false) {
    require '../db/connect.php';

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT city.cityId FROM city 
        WHERE city.cityName='"
        . mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['nameSend']))."' "
    );

    echo (mysql_num_rows ($query)!== 0 ) 
        ? mysql_result($query,0,'location') : 'Name Not Found !!!';
}
```

name.php that i request to process doesn't process at all
it only return the result just like code of the name.php
and i already using another server like WAMP / XAMPP
and still not getting result that i need

Comment: I find it really hard to get the question.

Comment: agree.. please explain your issue in better detail and be specific about which part of the code isn't working

Comment: If you are getting the php code back as a result in $.post, the server is not executing the php file.  The problem is the server and not the code

Comment: name.php that i request to process doesn't process at all
it only return the result just like code of the name.php
and i already using another server like WAMP / XAMPP
and still not getting result that i need

Comment: what happens when you open name.php in your browser?

Comment: when i open name.php is empty no text or anything

Comment: @Charles  how would opening in browser help? can't supply `POST` in url so page returns nothing

Comment: @charlietfl Well of course the condition that checks for the post variables should be left out for testing purposes. Check my answer, then it might make more sense. Maybe I am mistaken, but debugging through output in the browser seems to me like a pretty sensible procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole php code gets returned, your php code is probably not being executed. This might be a server configuration problem.

On the other hand, check what your mysql statement returns. Does it really only return the city name? To me it seems like you're fetching some city id there.

To generally clean up the return values of a php script, I recommend using json. Fetch the data from the database that you need, and store it in, e.g., `$object`. Then do the following:

```
$object = json_encode($object)
echo $object;
```

This will turn the data into a nicely formatted object that will be available in your jQuery code like so:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data); //data being the callback parameter
alert(json.attr1);
alert(json.attr2); //all attributes that the object had in the php code are accessible through this
```

**To summarize:** Debug your query, make sure your php server actually works (what happens when you open name.php in your browser directly?) and use clean callbacks through json.

**Edit**

To debug your query, at the very beginning of the script say

```
echo "SELECT city.cityId FROM city WHERE city.cityName='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['nameSend']))."'";
exit;
```

Open the script in your browser. You will see your query echoed out on the screen. Copy the query and paste it into your database panel (presumably phpmyadmin) and execute the query, see if it returns any error messages.

Comment: can you tell me how to debug it ?

Comment: i only get 

<?
 echo "SELECT city.cityId FROM city WHERE city.cityName='".mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['nameSend']))."'";
 exit;
 ?>

no changing on the post variable

Comment: Since you even see the php opening and closing tags, your php server doesn't seem to be running. If it ran correctly, you wouldn't see any php code in your browser (server side code never arrived at the client side). Make sure your server is actually turned on and supports php.

Comment: it's already turned on but really weird it can't process the php,
i try using xampp lite / portable it work with no problem at all

Comment: it looks because of the server error as long as i tried, i have use

 - XAMPP 1.7.7 lite USB --> works fine   
 - XAMPP 1.8.1 lite USB --> not working the name.php but any PHP file
   accept name.php works fine
 - XAMPP 1.8.1 installer --> same result as number 2
 - WAMP --> same result as number

is anybody fine same trouble or the solution of the newest XAMPP ?
is the apache is the trouble ?

Answer (score 0):

it looks because of the server software error as long as i tried, i have use

- XAMPP 1.7.7 lite USB --> works fine
- XAMPP 1.7.7 full installation --> works fine
- XAMPP 1.8.1 lite USB --> error
- XAMPP 1.8.1 full installation --> error
- WAMP --> error

the suspect is the newest apache server is not compatible with jquery plugins
or the php